# sql image datatype not displaying on asp.net page

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, image

I have an asp.net page that has an image tag that I'm using to display SQL image data but the string that I'm getting doesn't seem to work and I don't know why.

Here is the model that I'm using.

```
public partial class GetEmployeePhoto2_Result
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Photograph { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the controller

```
public ActionResult Photo(string id)
{
    btprodEntities p = new btprodEntities();
    //var photo = p.GetEmployeePhoto(id).ToArray();
    var photo = p.GetEmployeePhoto2(id).ToArray();
    ViewBag.Name = photo[0].Name;
    ViewBag.Photo = photo[0].Photograph;

    return View();
}
```

Here is the view

```
@model IEnumerable<employeeDirectory.Models.GetEmployeePhoto_Result>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Photo";
    //string base64 = ViewBag.Photo;
    //string imgSrc = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64;
    var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(ViewBag.Photo);
    var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}", base64);
}

<div class="container">
<header>
    <h1>@ViewBag.Name</h1>
    <div class="parent">
        <img class="rounded" alt="@ViewBag.Name" scr=@imgSrc >
    </div>
</header>
```

Here is the string that is being created for the image tag source

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4Q76RXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAEAA4BAgAQAAAAPgAAAA8BAgASAAAATgAAADEBAgADAAAAMDEAAGmHBAABAAAAYAAAAKoBAABIZXdsZXR0LVBhY2thcmQAaHAgcGhvdG9zbWFydCAxMjAAEQCaggUAAQAAADIBAACdggUAAQAAADoBAAAniAMAAQAAAGQAAAAAkAcABAAAADAyMTADkAIAFAAAAEIBAAAEkAIAFAAAAFYBAAACkQUAAQAAAGoBAAABkgoAAQAAAHIBAAACkgUAAQAAAHoBAAAEkgoAAQAAAIIBAAAFkgUAAQAAAIoBAAAHkgMAAQAAAAQAAAAIkgMAAQAAAAAAAAAJkgMAAQAAAAAAAAAKkgUAAQAAAJIBAAB8kgcAEAAAAJoBAAABoAMAAQAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAQAAABgAAAAcAAAACgAAADIwMDQ6MDE6MjEgMTM6NTc6NTYAMjAwNDowMToyMSAxMzo1Nzo1NgATAAAACgAAAC0AAAAKAAAAHgAAAAoAAAAAAAAACgAAAB4AAAAKAAAA3wMAAGQAAAAFRKJAAPBEokBEov/8AAShAwADAQMAAQAAAAYA//8BAgQAAQAAANQBAAACAgQAAQAAAB4NAAAAAAAA/9j/4AAHSkZJRgD/2wCEABALDA4MChAODQ4SERATGCgaGBYWGDEjJR0oOjM9PDkzODdASFxOQERXRTc4UG1RV19iZ2hnPk1xeXBkeFxlZ2MBERISGBUYLxoaL2NCOEJjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY//AABEIAHgAoAMBIQACEQEDEQH/xAGiAAABBQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAQIDBAUGBwgJCgsQAAIBAwMCBAMFBQQEAAABfQECAwAEEQUSITFBBhNRYQcicRQygZGhCCNCscEVUtHwJDNicoIJChYXGBkaJSYnKCkqNDU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6g4SFhoeIiYqSk5SVlpeYmZqio6Slpqeoqaqys7S1tre4ubrCw8TFxsfIycrS09TV1tfY2drh4uPk5ebn6Onq8fLz9PX29/j5+gEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoLEQACAQIEBAMEBwUEBAABAncAAQIDEQQFITEGEkFRB2FxEyIygQgUQpGhscEJIzNS8BVictEKFiQ04SXxFxgZGiYnKCkqNTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqCg4SFhoeIiYqSk5SVlpeYmZqio6Slpqeoqaqys7S1tre4ubrCw8TFxsfIycrS09TV1tfY2dri4+Tl5ufo6ery8/T19vf4+fr/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/AKwU4PFNK1QhhXisoBvNlx030mNG5FGfLX6U/wAo4pMaHLETUiw9jQkMkWH2pTBx0p2Ad5PA4o8vFMQm3AqOQcVVwKsiZqnLArdVH5VLAoXluscRZRg1RUGlcRLnmpYrZ5vZfWmB0PGOCOaTAxTEMYAd6zI4/nk6cuaiQ0b0W1QFbjjvU4VD0IqgHbB2pyoMmgBZpI7aFpZSAq1iXWvytxbW+F/vPyfypNjC019twW5iyP7y/wCFbkZSeNZIyGVuQRTQAyYFQSLTArMtQOnNKwGfqS4tmrLBAHvUtCLdjbrNISecVqpDwOOKGNEMlm21FWQjaKjNlOBlZjUjsRG2uFP+uJ/GpLND84PXeaEFrF9VuwNp+de2ccUoa5XqhP8AwH/69O4WHi5nXkxNgf7Jp66mAfmjI/P/AAp8wWILi5TUbyG3JKx9SPetCe0gjjCBAAtVbS5Ud7GXNaW7NwuCfQ1No832W9e3Z/3TDIz2NRF6lzSsbRlibgOp+hqJwK0MSB1FV5FGKYjO1FQbR8dhWOiD0qHuCNrSIvlkYjqQK0kj4pjIygJpNgqLFEZj5qtZJl5P+upoS1E2dH9nGAMUpth6UWHcQW+M/wAqYbZQScUWC5nSWTDWo5lA2BcH2NUtT+1yXahVJ56Z7Vol7tha3KupxypcjauBgZHXFXdLtPtU26YH7nY4rJGjuaD6VH2eQD/eqF9L2/dlcUEkLWM46Tv+NV5Le6XpNmncTRSuI7lI2LPle9RRxs2Mk4ouTY0LWSaKP93FuUnOatpeyD71u4/CquBIyunIO4DqDSggpuByMZpDDFQabGDKwBzmY9qOoM64QDPSl8oHjjNOxNxjQioGTDGkUmQSxYk8wDtg+1Zt7LtkVskANjAGSTVrYq5iTXLSXTb93XAytbeiIzMZT91QV+prFbmjehqstRstUZkLLVeWPIoEZ2oJ/osn0/rVKNQEH0oEbFjDi1jOOvNWo4hjp3oArFl7kfnUCyJ+8RGB4yBViJFboD1FJo4Bm3HgecT+tLqB14kSR9kbr7tnpT2hRAHQAYIB56imSOeEYzWdc4ViF69BQCZTuXEUXLn72MY5Pc1SmKoxL549KtIq/UwJpYjcsYwx3GtnSdQjiK2zR8E/eHrWC3NZbG2wFRMKuxnciYVDIOKLA2Z2pDFnKcdB/WsuFy3GB0pWJudJbx7beMf7IqeNOKbQ7nMqSAAWOB6moLIsZZHdiWxijqIl+dHyJH/OtWwQBQFOASScfWmkFzpYNHtZY1kYHcewNSNosAjOzeGxx83FFxFdtMiCBhcSDIyOagigSKfIldiOgJ6/pVpCuyrqEXmPn+Fs/gazZ5miOJBuGMc1Mnyu5rD3lYypWjEzMnQ+tXNKtnd/PPC5+UnvWcVd3LlsbgncrhMMRxzxUT3Nwud0QGPU1ZmyE3c3/PNfwNRPeSY/1Y/OjUWhSvLl3t5EMZG4dc1UtUJY00ibm8LzYApXpxT1v1Ucg07Bc5uSXAkGeQhYH3qpZyuNzMcBvbiouMlZJI8uJSR1q1Yys0eWkOc0dQRuWiTSTQRx3TjzCRnJ4rWaO7t5Rvu5XSP3x2+ta2JcgubkrHIc854qm7kmNwSCw602NIHm3SbZBjd3HQ1mz3kMt49tIoVFA/eHoT6Upq6uKLadinPYwgHc2A3decVaswwiSCEusXUs3Ws9tDU0olAQAdKXfuLK3K+hpgQFNsuB0ZWx+VZ0khE4TsaERIjnClWGRn0qSxgy31rVRMXKxtx6VLKA4jJHripTpEmP9U2fpSdhp3PPnu/P3nYqArjA+tJHwcVzmpcnfMLAfSksZAIwT61TeoI3tLnb7ZAyqxAzwMZ6VsXl0pE+wYAxnnv/AJFaxehMlqRXmfJY/SoutvCfrRLccdh4IEyZqpfadE8zHGAf4RxS6DtqOEMcUIAH196fGuIyx61Ld2UtETwrlSewqCJtzSH/AGiKGAiODIqn1IzVBEilaPc5ErDdipbsO1ylIfL1B4zyP/rZq/pc25wDj1renLQ5pxO106eN7VfmAI7Zq4GB6EGsZLUuL0scNYeGbK0TdMTcufXhR+FQahoVs5eW3PkNj7v8P/1qqUUkUtTBs7/y41ZlQuDwdozV2G/uJ8t5iAZ4BSufqdG0U0XtOuJzfIHKFVVmPGMYH+NWkffa3Ge9dEFZGEndljzxKsqk/wAK7fyzRbfPZxse2auSuyYhv3SZHrU12f3g+lT0L6oqO2TipGbEaj15NQiizHxbmsjedyICRudifzqpdBLqOEmZ1x6n+dSkbWcCM4zkcis2UjFvtq6qCSVLAYH6VLp8gRmK84U1cGZSRs2926ggAfnVmLUpkcshA7da0vdGdrMk+2Rs+0xzBQO0Tf4VTu4WuGMaFlRxhht5GfrUyd0awVtGUV8KQk5ad1HptoHhAbvlv5FX08sH+tYpWNWrouQ6NHpVrPIszzSOuMsAMDPaqllLm1lz3Gf1rZaWMu4W7fuix6qmP6Vet8ppqD61Quo2H749zU94cOPpU/ZL+0VlGTSsfmFQUWmbFvWNCC1wzdkGB9STVS6EoS0fzLg+gyf1qrqBmju3Au3VWwQMngVIPYpn5mDSXTk+pycfrU0saw4xdyNn+6p/xoM9xgkX/nvMf8/Wp4r9Ik27Xb3LYqhG4dX2zsBCT8o7/WpG1cqufJ/M1i6h0qJFLq0pjPEantmpINUMkWQycHGTU89yuWxeuX8y12sRuI5xXKPObUSRj7wziuqaskc0Xdsl0qRp7WZmPG4D+v8AhW5cfu7ONfahbB1IrQbplp142ZjS+yX9oiXpSZ+YVBRYkP7iub+0yJcTEPhFJBX1omSi7YIY7fe33n/lUWsws6wyIpJwVOP0oBrQyvJlbjYw+oqWXL7VyAR6mpvYlJjY7WSV9qyRg+7Vow6PGOZ5Sx9F4p3GoFBftUshOSvHUmnyQXTRFjMNo571zG+pKLBjnfO34Ci0sybzyRI20OOvcHFC3Q7HUTMoJwa53XLYgeavVf1FehV1iccdGWPD0W6wXj70pNampPllWltEpfEPs02puPeqs7ZlJ96mWkUUtZMAeMCgfeFQWSyt+6FcvComv3jPTeSRSluiTaDZwFHSpxAs6BJQCByKNyiE6TApJTg/QGpktFRSNsbD/dxSsBWutPNw4JZRgYwRSDTCg+S72/gcVPKBkK15vwV6jjmnyi9+zvwANpzzWJpqPjt7uUfNIg+uTU+nWsqaiC0udjqeB1qoW5kDvY1768kSQqkRZR3FZF7ffaImjxtbBGD1rqnLdHOtjQ8OkJpcWeoZuPxq1IvmXBZiOO1aNe6iVuTySBI8D0rO3FmNRNlwJF4FGSTn0rM0Fkf5AK5+3ULqMzbgDnAok9STYjRwuQQR7VYiJUHPGaBkoY+tG+kA0sD1xUZJxwM0xHOfb2Dghex7UTX85icBcAg54rnsaXHR3dzKgManafwqxYrc/bVlkYBQQSKcdJIbu0bV0yKAY1diemKzZ7czr+8jAP8Aezgiuyors5obEOj3vkXJt2JdCTtYdM1rrJmTJ7mkpe6hpatkk78ZqmX+bA4pT3KjsSKxxkmm+aQeOlQUEzHyw3vWKiI91PIzELuxgClLcRdinKjZCHI9+a19MheVWaXgCmhluS1Qj5WIPvVd4JEH3d3uKAICfUUwyY7VRJ//2f/bAEMACAYGBwYFCAcHBwkJCAoMFA0MCwsMGRITDxQdGh8eHRocHCAkLicgIiwjHBwoNyksMDE0NDQfJzk9ODI8LjM0Mv/bAEMBCQkJDAsMGA0NGDIhHCEyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMv/AABEIAMgAuwMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAfAAABBQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAQIDBAUGBwgJCgv/xAC1EAACAQMDAgQDBQUEBAAAAX0BAgMABBEFEiExQQYTUWEHInEUMoGRoQgjQrHBFVLR8CQzYnKCCQoWFxgZGiUmJygpKjQ1Njc4OTpDREVGR0hJSlNUVVZXWFlaY2RlZmdoaWpzdHV2d3h5eoOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4eLj5OXm5+jp6vHy8/T19vf4+fr/xAAfAQADAQEBAQEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAQIDBAUGBwgJCgv/xAC1EQACAQIEBAMEBwUEBAABAncAAQIDEQQFITEGEkFRB2FxEyIygQgUQpGhscEJIzNS8BVictEKFiQ04SXxFxgZGiYnKCkqNTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqCg4SFhoeIiYqSk5SVlpeYmZqio6Slpqeoqaqys7S1tre4ubrCw8TFxsfIycrS09TV1tfY2dri4+Tl5ufo6ery8/T19vf4+fr/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/ANPaFPNPUZp4BJ5HSnogGPWtBlcLmVqmVeelKqjzH/CpVXAoARVGegpwTv0FOVPyp20jvQA0JzUgXj3pQKViEGWOB3ND0ATHcUuOPasfUPFWk6epD3Cu4/gTk1xGp/EG+ugyWaJBGf4jyanm7Bc9KkmggTzJZEjA7lsCsSTxHo4kdPtsWQ4zg5+vNeST393dOWnnkkLc/MxqON8nkkEUczFc9uttVsb7/j2u4pP91quY3MuK8OjuzHJuQsCDncDiug0zxffWsiZmMiA8pIc007jvc9TZeaay+1ZGm+K9P1IKC/lS9NrVtgq4BUgiqsMhI4phXHarGMGm46cUAQFeMcUigdO9TFeaQLzQBCwqI/5zVl171CQc/WgCM4IphXPPFSkHPWoiCDwaPQRaGMU9cYqqrnHJ7VLG/PPNFgHKMO5GeoqVemahH3m+tSp0osBIvapAOKYKevA/GjQB+MVxHjLxK0StYWfMmMO47Vt+JdWOnWDrC2J3GE9vevNWt3mmMszsWY5Ynqawk+Z2KSuZiwtKSTnJ5p62DsT8hrpNP0hp2JSP5R3IrqF8PxJbL8uWxWjjdalxhc8xmsJI2GVI+opj2Ukaq+CVY9a77UNJRplVV6Ke1UpNOJsVjK/xdxUbLUr2V2cU1u6HkEUioQcgfhXSajpxihR1Tr7VmraMWIKnBqebUPZtEcYb5ZULAr6dq7jwt4oYMtrfMSp4WQ9vrXD+XJBJtyfpipI3eFxt+6TzkVcZJEuPc9uC7lyvQ8g+tJs6elcp4P8AEX2hVsLlsn/lmx9PQ12WzgZz+Fa6ENWKxQ+lJsPpVkrkGgrigm5SZfaomXI+lXWT2qJk68UDKhGBTCnPerRQVGVIJAoCxzS+IbNT+8W4jH+3Aw/pViLxJpRYf6bGp9GyP5iud/tSdAd9nIPo2f6Uh11f4obj8QDWKm9x2Ouj1bTpWJS+tzn/AKar/jV6GeKQfJIrf7pzXAHVLFuZLXJ/24AaaLrSGOTaxLnqfIx/Kmqmgcp6SOOSDS7wqsT0rzuO40kZ2Epx/BJIv8jU/wBsQRMYL67xj7n2hmX8Qc0e0uh8pBrt4LzUpXdjsXhRnpS6Lpj38m8r8v0rB+0xz3ZjIO/OST0ru/CtwnnLCoPTsOBWlKAXSOistKitbbYoGSKneIKmGq5INo4zVOU7geprRo0TvsZ0kEbMSVyelVZY4l42DA6Vckfax/qKz55AW9KwnodESvLHE4wUBA7VSNvAD/qh+VXXdfLzjn6VTeQHpj8qxbNUVbnTba4fcq7T7Vm6jopWHfECcegrbBAzx+lL5mIyD0x6VPQmUUzirOaWxvI2GVZT1r2rSrxdQ0uC5ByWXn6147qCo9yzKMEV3/gO5DaZLCSflbOMV1UneOpxTXY68jjpSEDFNLcUharMhCMqeKiZc5FPLAf/AKqYx60AMIx2qMjnpUhb2qPd/tH8qLDKM+l2kinEC/hWTJotsX/1eB9a6NVOMHHFJ5O/sD9a5pamq0OUfQrdnf7w7Uz/AIR6E4+Y/lXSyQZkcDjmnLbYUEgEVFiro5Y+GIychxj3FVbnRGsYXkXawx2FdskQ2niqt/b7rOQKueOlF2JpWPHvMdNVZSOhNd54TRzdJ2yMk+1cPcgjXCOCd/Nej+EggE8rsoCgDJIrvofBc5lqztVl3AJjoOtZOo6naWW4SzAH60uq3x0+KBBtElwu+LBByvTPFcTqo89P37R7idwY9fpTqN8uhcXrY0rjxLZM5VZOarDUUnb5WzXGzywxzna6ZHbGK6Pw2ttezCIsBIfujsa5YpzOlVOXcsXF4Y15rLm1uON8YJ+lamuWJt4yQRtPTBFcc1xbpIfNGVzzg81z68xrOemh0EGv27Nhga0luFli3oQR3xXIRSQMcR7SB2JGa19OudnAAKnqO9WldWJjU7lG9/d3hXqOwrX0i9jt4G3zTxEngxuVNZupIJL6N4zlSuDx0rqbDwybmwglWVMOM4ZTVQuomUviYLrO0DZq10PTc6t/NalXXLkH5dX3f70Kn+op0nhCXGQ0P5n/AAqrN4UmHRY/wei7XUmxdXX78H/j8tXH+1Fj+RqQa/qHXbZuOn3mH9Kxv+EXusHEJOPRgagbQLxesco+gz/KnzSsLlOi/wCEhu+9nEf92b/GmnxJN2sG/wC/y1zjaVexc5mX6qai+y3o43yfrVKT6i5T1loQnJApiofTFWmyRjqaRk2r0pCRREQM79OcVIQEHTNSGP8Ae/gDQyUiittGT71HNGht3DyLGpB+djgCrm3nBxVDXbczaNcqoydmRSSvoUux5brPhy7s9YSYlZbd34mjPFdr4WsontJHkTcd2FLc9quyWcKaNbQy7I0ZAQWIHPtV3TrMafa+SGz8xOa7oLlVrmfKlK6Rj+IokgWFliBGSPxrkLu3nmt5GZOMHABIyfqOlel3dqlzDslQMtczqOlXCqywSK6ns3BpSfcn2bZ5gtoynEvB6cnmt3R4JVdBENxJGfTitaHwzPPcbpSiL6sc10+m6PFbPGI+UXlmI6kVEIPdstRszJ8Qw3Asj5pVmIyV6YrzuaBGYkkqD0HpXq+vbX9MH1rirmwWZiMhWHTjiuLm5Jux1zhzxRz1rZgMTuDDHBz3rWtQ8MoB+YDnOaE0qZW+QLj0BGK0rawlBAkAX+dVzdWZKk0JLbGTEqHGXCn06V6To8YXSbfjA28c9q48xxRWgjcgKTgH3Nd7YxeXY2qHnbGo+tUm2rDkkkOdBtqs0XPTNaUseHIHAxUbRAjtSZmmZ3lhe1MMYz0FXinpio9nNIdyq0QIxiovIFXymCKTyx6j8aYkbG0DoKR0JWrjQjOOBTHXb0GauxlczmX9630FGAeDUrD52PoBTQmfwNSUN2hscDNI8YaFweQQRipNuDn1pQOvpTsO5x4iOoeKIxdKDbW/KxnocDiuhuConAXG0ioJbPypnc4Y7soRwwHpmpAN+OQSpwcV1Q2LqNO1iWRQYgR1HWsq7IUZHWtESbSR2rG1CXDMd34U5WtciLd7GXe3awsOfm+ta9rPt09HkYID6mubfTpr26VnbZETmr+o6Xb3EEccjuY07B8c1nCTNZJIg1rUIVujEzDAHY1z0zRuRLHINp461BrKxJc+Wk5dAoUEnmorCCBcRlvl9DXBJvmd2dCkmkXoHCqAOB7Gr0EgYjJOKoG3MSkxNuX0p0T7WVt1JSK2NO8UHT2BOSW49jXoGgt9p0m1lfOQgHHtXn8jhrWMk5G4cV6BokZTSrVUO1cZIreGxhV2L0hyx9qh/WpZB8/WmlcDNN7mCIGXNM24qcjJphWkMjI59qZtP+TUpHFNwe1Ajo+Ow+lRSgbdx/8A11baNwOGP44qB4nzgyA/8BrUwTKGwbmyOwzTMAcVO6OGbkHK1Dh+uFpWLTG5PSjjr6cGg7gfu8fWoVlY3UkWwBVUHOe5pWGNvLIXSkLK0T/3gM1VWySwRVR3cucs7nljWlk91P51Tu5GeXydmMJvBzz1xVxk72Ku7WMy8DfZyCeaomETGMtyO4q/P88Y5PB5FU1Gxh3FdDWhKZzXiPWBa6gtuCVXHJFUHvQYiFuCWI4Ga6G80uG71ZZpACF5ANWp4baCMusCZHoK5+RNe8aLc8vuJJVuGZuQTgVEs8qchWzW5rEpNyT5WMVBbbG+8vWuR6Gyiug3S7+SWTYwOPQitOYBRkcHNQ+VErqyjkGpipeVTz045qFq7I0SsrHVeF9KttRR/tUbSLEAwG4jn8K7ZV2BVT5QBgAVjeE7Qw6UZAADI3f0FbWH3D7vX3rrZyyd2JtoY/LinEN6CmMGH8PP1pE3GYphHapMnH3aYT/sn8qAGkDtTdp7fzp2fY0mf84oA68xkVC6diK0nQelVZRitbHPcypl2sTjpVUgZNWrlhuaqJfnrQUmU7+4mDxWlqQLibPzkZEajqx/z1oFo9uhdbiSVgoGHxzjr07mmWIM15dXOMlm8pP91f8A6/8AKrtywtYyZMbsdM01FvYbaKtxemOxE0EZllfAjT1b39B6mshcQ3IluNYinucYeKMDGT2HfArprezh+wJc3K7FIyIVOF/H1rlNb1iHTT5lpHDECcMERQT+NUoxixpt7Fi6Vo5D12mqe3L/AMq0rg+dbxyqeGUH86zGOw+orUNmJ5DPJuAORUV3BI6Y21OL0RHk8+uKrXmsxIPw5qGkVGVmczqemk/McZrLjsZI5BwMVe1HVjNOQp+X3rJn1Nk6HmvNklfQ7FJJamh5QDYx0GetXLOINKpk4Gaw7W7eefBBOK2IJPmweB1FNJxd0CkpbHqOmajpslulvbXCDYMbGO0/rWgVzg14us02NyODtGVbuK7Dw54llKJHcHcnTr0rojqcrR3JHFMZaVXEiB0OVIyDSEVViSIrTcYqTHNMIosFyMjFJt9qeaQ9etFh3OvfUbM5xcxH/gQqjLqFuQ376M88YNeZ42A77PUk+qyH+tNNxGn8eoJj/pk39VNafIxUF3O4nuY3LlXHWqMs4SN3z0UkVzTTrHAtx9tvQjcZ8sf/ABs0sN4JyViubiZhyUaPH/sg/nSSbLskdno9o0FjCGX5yu989s81ka2u67hjeVsvIBt9BmuljbMoxx5kQ28YyawtcgVWUw26syMCXx92t2rIyi7y1F8R6nHbWWFOyNE6fSuKtkQ6T/a99Dl5AWjRhwi9uPWtDxXKZtP25IEhCk1FrsajT7WzGNjBVwOM9Kxk3Y6Iqxo6bdJqGiwzR9CuOPaqzsA5BH1rP0yZtJlktTxGrZUexqzc3CMfMRuvr2qoVE9ypU3uQ3SMoJC5XuMVz2owrJuKM6E9jXWxvHLDyeQKzb60SVDt7etVNXRklrqcFJC4chmz71AbVWJznP8AM1r39jJG5C5/OobeAIQXOa86S1OuMbodaW3lR5UEe5q0jYNJIQseF6VAzlIy3NQ/I1SsiK1mJXjBG7kY7Vt6Ug+2qqgAZyK57SA0kLEN0Y8Edea6jSQFvEd8jjvXXCxyXuehaZMQgjJ4I4rQJ4xzXPWs+CGUjFaxvIscyKCR0zVktFg46+lNPWoBcx9S4/OkFxGwyH4o0FYmpM1EbmP++MfWk+0x/wB5fzo0EdRJp9yR8uozD6op/pVaWyvR/wAxJse9uhq9NqQPESge5rPmuXcctz7mtlF9Tk5VcoT2d42f+JgufX7Mv+NWLOF4rV0afzZM7twTbxVG5uj/AHhTLW/Mcwdz8nRvpVqyL5XYvtM5Rv8AnpEd6k+lRXCreWobcQZCSQKkuE8mRZgCV6MAOqnrVPzBY3DocMjdPp7VbRCd9jmNYgE0Ji6+W4xz2pbu1Oo6fA4bEkLA9euK19StHLrFBFnjc5xwPxrPtHMczQsABKOPY9655Rs7HXCV0Zk9v9ojypxPF0H94elZ7S74xzj2reuLZlIkTO5fvAVkX9oZA91AQCBmWLnJP94f4VhOPVHTSqW0ZRS+e1kwfu1eW8WXDK361kyOki9c1QaVon+V8ClGu46MqdJPVGrrJiNuH3fMK55XJPByB2qa6uWnXaSKqq+3GW59cVjN80rjj7sbFosTgdqr3UgjiyT70jTbR1HftVaOKfU7yO2gG9nPT29aIQcnZBOSSuaGgwKLUF8hnyR+ddbp2kqZVeSTIxxVjS9GSzjVZo4yw7A1seWUI6AemK67WOZMSO3VPlRqvRS4hKscY/ix0qoXWNc5x/Ks+W6kuZ0ghPBPzN6DvS8hlyQ38al/tgKev2UH+RqpNq8TbBFqdsHHDq8Oefz4rWRzGAARgCiSKzvhsurWKQ+rKM/nRyoV30MiK/BkBlvLB074hIP86z7nW76G5kji02OaNW+WRY+GFa1z4TsZMm2kMLdlddyj+v8AOnRaVewRLEEDbRjIIwaOQm7R2MjYyScAGqjXSk7Aeabqdz5aEDOe/NYdnOxuRn7pPauptXsc8Y3Vy5dSckDIPvVQuWXb0NXb+NkwwHbvWZ5mJM4NS9C73Vze0e/W6jaynb99COM/xp6/0p+p24iVCDzjgn0rC8uQyJPbOUuI+Ub19Qfara6ut+yxzfJNEOYj3+nrWtNqSsYVE4vmRZgmebeW+by0yQf4vSseW2nSNpXIMgbzAqnJX61fkYxnzUOCTz7+1NgRfs0rSy7EeQE5GSMDkUShzaMcKnLqtiGOTzow4+90IqrcWPIlhOJBzir6f8fEaQxMokHyqccgd6zda8Q6ZorQpeTOkk2Sm1C3Q4ycdBXNJcujOpSUkY9xYW17I3lMLa6PVW+4x/pXO6nb3Fk5E8TKwOOnH4Gu2ljtNUiS5hkA3jKyJyrfWs2d9Ssz5TbZIz0WVQwrGcFuaxqtaHCSXIJxg57UkUVxOcxxOy56gZFdXPeSc7tNsj6gwjmoorfUtXuPLQiGNRztXaiD8KUafYbq3OP1CaW0uPJkUBiu7r0FWNE8Qrpdx5iRRSSYwGbmtnVPCltPqsNjZTS3F7jdO2BsiX/aPY+1XrfwJpiwpIs0rSnJwcbR9fStacORXZg5SlI7O0lN1FFdOqjzI1dQB0yM0+5uUiGWOaxpdRg0yySLzMmNQuP8KxZL661Jwqo6hztRe7e5qXLm0Ro9NzVl1M3tw0UGSqfeYdPpWvY2ywIWIy7fpVWx01NOs0TrMw+Y471pIrKAMHP0p2sGpLxtwaaCQwNPOSQPWmlctmmBcScbfmGfrTvtER9fwNUJmwuA3J9Krhjj7pNIC3q0pMzZJxisuFyXAHHvmrWpSZck55rPgfL/ANa0luZwWh0sw+0WCMucbcflWKXPmc/qK27UFtKIHO0msNyN/POK0l0ZnDdouw/Lzxmo7yxS6/eIdsoHBHGaWCQDsenpU6tlsHIyMis4uzui5K6MWHVZrST7PqClgvCuvUfWtaGaB3SRMOnueCPTFUdQtEushjg9mpbC3aNCrjvwVFdVOXNozkqQcNUaMt+32o337tYokbeT94jHavEPEGq3Gr6u0kj58sY57ZOSPw4H4V6lqtw0SNHLCzx4x8nBx9K4WDStFjvTI8koUnJjk4/Xv+dZVYtvcqn3Oj8M6ykOlwWcwARDhXUdveuocW08AI+ZD6HjNecPaJZu0mk3iHJyYZG+Vv8ACpdN1jVBfKrWzwxHr6CuaV0zqjJM7NtKtWJw7rxms3WpL21soItGljQEkTFiN/bBGfxp39qCbEU8nlD++vU0n2Fbs74ZU2HoS2SfelJNmkWhsF1aaXpjQWikyuMyyv8Afc+pPesz+2bidRa2YAXo0p7n2qS80+YFoVVyrcb2UgY9qt6do5WIFRhe7two/wAaTjJ6ti2K5gXau/Lyep5JrZ0mzKOJ3wGxhQP4aRIIVkCQ/Mx+9If6elasCbAMA47mmloMWVj5iDOamG5uAMj3quzZnGOQBzxU6MRyOB70JATA5OMflQw+bGTSJyc/qKc2ewNOwFe7bbH2OTiqu4n+P9Kkv22qnrnpUQYgYx+tEUDZLqHB+5ge9Z9uRv3cn1IFFFVLczi9Dp9MwdMk3DcQ3GfpWLcKfOPyheaKK1n8KJh8THRegcj8KuRAjkZbAoorJblvYqzndId2Ku6W21iq5x60UVcH7xE17pb1C2juIiroHB65FcBq+nRQ3LRRwgKR3OaKKqskZ0tjK/sMyk+WhP8AwGnxaL5eRJG+09ewNFFRF2eho0rHQ2GlQvGm62iwMfOUGa2XxDblYY1wBwKKK2lJtakRik9CpFK4UbkQeg2Dim3F0xG0ck8baKK5GdS1JbOERrkgbm61cbCjHJHtxRRTewiqg3SyEg5AwKsKwC+3bNFFCYE0WcccVMRhc9f50UVTWhNzG1aTbLAvdpBSgnH3c/hRRWaKZ//ZAA==
```

Here is what I see when the page loads
[image]

Here is what I see when I inspect the image tag
[image]

I've tried adding this to the view

```
base64 = base64.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
```

I've also tried using this on the view

```
base64 = base64.Replace("\r\n", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "");
```

Does anyone have any idea what is causing the problem and how to fix it? All I have left on this project is to display the photo on this page.

Comment: Your img tag has a scr attribute, try changing to src

Comment: I can't believe I didn't  see that. Thank you  @Daniel, that worked. I feel like an idiot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies with a typo in your `<img>` tag. You are setting your base64 value to a scr attribute. Scr is not an attribute of `<img>`.

By modifying your html tag from:

```
<img class="rounded" alt="@ViewBag.Name" scr=@imgSrc >
```

To

```
 <img class="rounded" alt="@ViewBag.Name" src=@imgSrc >
```

After making the change you'll be able to see the selfie you've kindly included.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It was driving me nuts that I couldn't get that to work.